# Split Blog Into Two Sections?

Tags: users, blog, split

Alright, so this is my vision for a website I am currently looking to relaunch... As of right now, my site's blog consists of posts in the form of products linking to Amazon via WP Zon Builder (plugin). Now I am looking to open the blog up to others who are interested in writing content for the site. Is there a way to split my blog up into two sections, like the following:

• original posts
• new posts

Basically I don't want my original posts taking over the site, especially since there are over 400 of them. In a way, I kind of want to archive them and have the focus of the site be the new blog posts being submitted by my authors/users.

I'm thinking of a possible workaround. Is there some kind of plugin that can split my blog up by users? I can assign all the current posts to an individual user account, thus making room for the new users.

Hopefully this isn't confusing. Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

My first thought was to create 2 main categories. Exclude one from the wordpress loop on index.php and then only show that category on a different page.

The only problem with this method is that the users would have to make sure they are posting in the correct category. However if you used a plugin (like adminimize) to restrict the categories users could post into it should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Archiving your posts can be viewed in 2 ways:

1. You can set all your original posts to **Draft**, thus they will be not be available on your blog anymore. (bad for SEO).
2. The other work around if you still want users to access your original posts using their old links or via search results, you can just **assign the original posts to a user** and **exclude all posts from a specific user** in any query you use to display posts on your blog. This way you will only show the new posts on your site, but leave your original posts reachable via direct links or search results.

   ```
   //exclude Posts Belonging to an Author
   //replace 12 with the ID of the user assigned to all the original posts
   $query = new WP_Query( 'author=-12' );
   ```

Because you assigned your original posts to a user, you can still access them by going to the **yoursite.com/author/{username}**.